# In 'Kim is tall', is 'is tall' a VP?

Tags: constituents, constituency

Do we say that in

*Kim is tall.*,

the *is tall* is a [constituent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics))?

Well, the standard answer is clearly Yes (see below). My questions are:

1. What is the linguistic evidence for the assertion that *is tall* is constituent? Below I give two pieces of evidence, arguably neither of which is individually conclusive. Are there more?
2. Is there any evidence against that assertion?

In a previous version of this post, I also asked:

'I assume that the following is an equivalent question: is *is tall* a verb phrase (VP)? (Am I right to assume that?).'

I have since learned enough about all this at least to be sure that this is indeed so: a VP simply *is*, by definition, a constituent whose head is a verb.

**Literature does treat copula *be* + complement as a VP**

I understand that there are many kinds of theories of grammar out there. I am interested in the type of grammar exemplified by e.g. [CGEL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468). I would be tempted to describe this as 'mainstream "standard" phrase-structure grammar', but please keep in mind that I am not a linguist, and this descriptor is almost certainly inadequate.

It is clear that CGEL would say that *is tall* is a constituent. On p. 50, they say that in *he is ill*, the *is ill* is a VP:

[image: constituent structure of 'he is ill' from CGEL, p. 50]

As far as primary literature, I'm sure that there must be legion examples in which it is clear that the copula ***be*** is considered part of a VP . So far, I have been able to locate one such example: [this source](http://lohndal.com/wp-content/uploads/copula06.pdf). The context is how theta roles get assigned in sentences such as

[1] *He is a good player*.

> An important suggestion, going back to Marantz (1984), says that it is
>   the entire VP (the verb and its internal argument) that assigns the
>   verb’s external θ-role, and not only the verb. ... Furthermore, it is
>   also a common assumption that the internal argument is responsible for
>   selecting the subject, that is, the postcopular element decides what
>   can be able to be a subject. Hence the subject gets its role from the
>   internal argument: [some examples are given] We see that the
>   complement seems to restrict the external argument alone, not being
>   affected by the presence of the copula. That is, **the entire VP
>   selects the subject, but since the copula is empty, it does not
>   contribute in any sense.** [emphasis mine]

For my present purposes, the point is that the paper implies that the copula + its complement is a VP.

**Showing constituency of some other kinds of word sequences containing verbs**

Consider

[2] *He gave John a book.*

We suspect that *gave John a book* is a constituent. To show this, we note that the following sentence is acceptable:

[3] *He gave John a book, and she did, too.*

In the second coordinate, the pro-form *did* substitutes for *gave John a book*. And since it is widely accepted that only constituents can be substituted by pro-forms, it follows that *gave John a book* is a constituent.

If in [1] instead of *is* we had *seems*, the same test would show that *seems a good player* is a constituent:

[4] *He seems a good player, and she does, too.*

But if we have *is*, this approach fails. As is well-known, copula ***be*** does not take ***do*** support, and so the following is not an acceptable sentence:

[5] *<sup>*</sup>He is a good player, and she does, too.*

In fact, I am not aware of any way one could replace *is a good player* (or *is tall*) by a pro-form, and thus I don't know how to apply the replacement test---arguably one of the cleanest kinds of constituency tests---to *is a good player* and *is tall*.

**Two arguments for the constituenthood of *is tall***

***Coordination***

We note that *is a good player* can be coordinated with something which is definitely a VP:

[6] *He is a good player and hits the ball hard.*

(We can show that *hits the ball hard* is a VP by the replacement test: *He hits the ball hard and she does, too.*)

This provides at least some evidence that *is a good player* is a constituent, i.e. a VP.

However, my understanding is that the ability to be a coordinate is not always a reliable indication of constituenthood---see e.g. p. 21 of [Carnie](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199583463). One well-known case where coordinates fail to be constituents is [right-node-raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_node_raising) (RNR, or, as CGEL prefers to call it, 'delayed right constituent coordination'). For example, in *F̲r̲e̲d̲ p̲r̲e̲p̲a̲r̲e̲s̲ and S̲u̲s̲a̲n̲ ̲e̲a̲t̲s̲ the food*, the underlined word sequences are coordinates but not constituents. If this was the only exception, we could say that the rule is, 'only constituents can be coordinated, except in RNR', and we know how to recognize RNR on grounds other than the fact that the coordinates are not constituents. (As Greg Lee pointed out, usually theories of RNR are formulated so that RNR is only apparently an exception. But it is still true that, for the purposes of constituenthood testing, one would need to pay special attention to RNR.) However, there are also counterexamples other than RNR; for example: *David introduced [[Chris] [to Tracy]] and [[Matty] [to Ken]]* (p. 368 of [Dalrymple](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0126135347)). Perhaps there is a way to identify and separately characterize this phenomenon, too. Also, as far as I know, there is no known counterexample with sequences involving verbs: in every case where the coordinates are word sequences that involve verbs and whose constituenthood status is independently known, the coordinates turn out to be constituents. Nevertheless, the coordination test does seem to require way more elaboration than e.g. the pro-form substitution test, and is therefore less clean and compelling.

***Being the item extracted by RNR***

We note that the following is an acceptable sentence (with big thanks to Greg Lee for coming up with it):

[7] *Harriet knows that Kim, but doubts that Marcia, is tall.*

This is again RNR, but the word sequence of interest, *is tall*, appears not as a coordinate but rather as the the shared material, the item extracted by the RNR. Sources such as McCawley's [*The Syntactic Phenomena of English*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226556247) say that such items must be constituents (see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=YCPURwLuprwC&pg=PA57&dq=%22smith+sells,+and+Jones+rents%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi98fKW1OPSAhUC7oMKHcmiBr0Q6AEIHDAA)). However, here, too, there are counterexamples: many sources (such as [this one](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4177950?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)) would say that the following is an acceptable sentence (although McCawley denies this, see the link above): *Smith sells, and Jones rents, luxury cars to insurance executives*. Here *luxury cars to insurance executives* is not a constituent even though it is an item extracted by an RNR. CGEL concurs that such things can happen (note 67 on p. 1343):

> We focus on cases where the delayed element is a single constituent;
>   occasional examples are found where what follows the coordination is
>   not a single constituent but a sequence: *It had to be ascertained
>   whether the managers had suitable people to put forward for possible
>   appointment from persons* [*registered with, or applying to,
>   t̲h̲e̲m̲ ̲f̲o̲r̲
>   ̲e̲m̲p̲l̲o̲y̲m̲e̲n̲t̲*].

So, again, although in the known problematic cases the extracted items do not involve verbs, the difficulty makes the RNR test seem less compelling.

**Summary**

We have two pieces of evidence that *is tall* is a constituent: it can be coordinated with other VPs, and it can be extracted by RNR. For both the coordination test and the RNR extraction test, it is known that the test is fallible in some cases (although none of these *known* problematic cases involve verbs). Also, [Carnie](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) seems to suggest that copular constructions are tricky when it comes to constituenthood analysis (p. 260).

The questions are:

1. Can you provide further evidence (in addition to the two pieces of evidence discussed above) that *is tall* is a constituent?
2. Is there any evidence that *is tall* is **not** a constituent?

Comment: *BE* is odd: it's always treated as an auxiliary, even when it acts by itself. So it can't be coded by *DO* because *DO* only codes non-auxiliaries--auxiliaries code themselves. Lexical *HAVE* is betwixt-and-between: it can code itself OR be coded by *DO*.

Comment: @StoneyB CGEL (pp. 113-114) distinguishes six uses of _be_, and in four of them it has all the properties of an auxiliary verb. However, in one of its uses, it takes ***do***-support in present tense negatives: _Why don't you be more tolerant?_ _Why doesn't he be more tolerant?_ . In this use it is therefore behaving like a lexical verb, which is why CGEL refers to this use as 'lexical ***be***'.

Comment: @linguisticum You're quite right; I'd forgotten that one. But I think that *DO .. be* is a syntactic workaround to maintain the lexico-semantic distinction between copular *BE* and the special behavioral sense of progressive *BE being*, as in *He's being very intolerant*--which of course is still coded as *BE*, not *DO*.

Comment: @StoneyB Whatever is really happening there, your observation that ***be*** is odd certainly stands unchallenged...

Comment: Negative "don't be" is also special as it is used in normal negative imperatives (without the pronoun "you"). We say "Don't be" just as we say e.g "Don't have" (in any situation where an imperative involving the auxiliary "have" makes sense...)

Comment: @sumelic CGEL (p.114): 'Pragmatically [i] (= a. _Why don't you be more tolerant?_ ;  b. _Why doesn't he be more tolerant?_) conveys "You/He should be more tolerant" and thus bears some resemblance to the imperative, but syntactically it is quite distinct from the imperative construction by virtue of having a present tense form, not a plain 
form. This is evident from the person-number contrast between _don't_ in [ia] and _doesn't_ in [ib], for imperatives with a 3rd person singular subject do not differ in verb-form from those with a 2nd person subject (cf. _Somebody open the door, please_).'

Comment: @linguisticturn As far as I understand it (probably not too well),the argument presented in that paper is about whether the theta role of the subject originates in the VP. It is often assumed that it cannot because the ascription of theta roles presumably is based on the semantics of the verb. With copula BE, the verb is thought to *have* no semantics, and therefore be incapable of assigning theta roles. However, it is not suggested that the adjective phrase does not occur within the VP - far from it. The argument in the paper is that it is the whole VP combination   ..

Comment: @linguisticturn ... of copula + adjective that determines the theta role of the Subject. So I don't think there's any argument that the adjective does not occur within the VP. And so anybody who accepts that will accept that the adjective forms a constituent with the verb (because it's  part of the VP!)

Comment: @araucaria I do see now that the paper says that the previous accounts also treated the copula as a part of a VP; previously I was under the impression that it was saying that at least one of these accounts didn't. I have updated my post accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @araucaria BTW, note that the VPs involving the copula are not the only place where it is the whole VP that assigns the theta roles On pp. 39-40, it is stated that examples such as 'She took the book' vs 'She took a rest.' vs 'She took a bus.' etc. show 'that it is the entire VP (the verb and its internal argument) that assigns the verb’s external θ-role, and not only the verb.' Therefore he freely assumes as noncontroversial that 'the external theta-role is a function of the complex V + complement.'

Comment: @araucaria The original contribution, as best as I can tell, is to show that this kind of analysis can be made to work for copular VPs, contrary to previous suggestions (I don't understand what these previous accounts do, exactly).

Comment: @linguisticturn If you want to get into that type of grammar (not my thing), you could read David Adger's 'Core Syntax'. That might make that paper a lot clearer :-) [Although I don't understand all of it myself]

Comment: "Why doesn't he be more tolerant?" is just totally contrived, compared to the natural "Why isn't he more tolerant" or, if I'm wrong and that expressed a slightly different meaning, the imperative should be inflected in the "to do" as well, "why don't he be", as in your "somebody open the door", because "do be" is an idiomatic verb phrase that should be inflected as a whole, not just on the "to be" part. if I might say so myself.

Comment: Now I'd look at the lexical aspects of do and be, because I suspect that doing is a progress and that being is used in the sense of an achievement and as such you actually mean "to become". Otherwise, to describe a continuous state, you'd have to use a progressive tense (edit: ... except with to be ... but then, as I said, you should default to "why isn't" to avoid **ambiguity** ... I guess, because the present progressive eludes me as a foreign speaker)

Answer (score 4):

In TSPE, McCawley often uses RNR as a test for constituency.  The raised node must be a constituent.  *is tall* passes this test: "Harriet knows that Kim, but doubts that Marcia, is tall."  So if "is tall" is a constituent, what would it be other than a VP?

I don't know what the problem is with using as a diagnostic, coordination with another VP.

Theta theory is a poor cousin of Fillmore's Case Grammar theory, where subjects of various sorts arise as complements to the verb.  (If you talk about theta roles instead of deep cases or semantic roles, you don't have to put Fillmore in your bibliography -- that's the point of theta theory.) I don't see the relevance to the question of whether "is tall" is a constituent.

Comment: Thank you so much, as always! As far as coordination, my guess is this: first one gets 'burned' by RNR (i.e. non-constituents appear as coordinates). OK, we make our peace with RNR: 'coordinates must be constituents---except in RNR.' Then we see this: _David introduced [[Chris] [to Tracy]] and [[Matty] [to Ken]]._ (p. 368 of [Dalrymple](https://www.amazon.com/Lexical-Functional-Grammar-Syntax-Semantics-34/dp/0126135347/)) Probably we can deal with that too, somehow, but  1. it's getting complicated, and 2. apparently, coordination is tricky---what further pitfalls may there be?

Comment: On the other hand... what about this example (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_node_raising#Non-constituents)): _[Smith loaned] and [his widow later donated] a valuable collection of manuscripts to the library._ Here the shared material, _a valuable collection of manuscripts to the library_, is apparently not a constituent...?

Comment: I see that in TSPE (p. 61), McCawley says that an analogous example, _Smith sells, and Jones rents, luxury cars to insurance executives_, is **not** acceptable... I was actually going to ask at some point if everyone really thinks so, because it sounded OK to me... and apparently it would also sound OK to B. Abbot, the author of the _Smith loaned..._ example (in "Right node raising as a test for constituenthood," Linguistic Inquiry **7,** 639-642 (1976))...

Comment: I've temporarily un-accepted the answer, until we clear this up a bit...

Comment: @linguisticturn, Those are interesting examples, and I don't understand them.  I have a name for them, though, due to Terry Langendoen, who in my very first course in syntax in 1965 called them cis-trans constructions.  They describe routes.

Comment: To your ear, as a native speaker, does _Smith sells, and Jones rents, luxury cars to insurance executives_ sound acceptable, though?

Comment: Yes, it does sound acceptable.

Comment: OK, good to know! Interesting that it didn't sound acceptable to McCawley (see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=YCPURwLuprwC&pg=PA57&dq=%22smith+sells,+and+Jones+rents%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi98fKW1OPSAhUC7oMKHcmiBr0Q6AEIHDAA))

Comment: What do we say now about the constituenthood of _is tall_? If I play the Devil's advocate and maintain that there is no good reason to believe that there is a VP in clauses in which the verb is copula _be_, what else can be said to me? Yes, I admit that _is tall_ passes coordination and RNR tests. But both of those tests fail at least sometimes; how do we know they aren't failing this time, too?

Comment: Evidently, we don't know that they aren't failing this time, too.  If you thought of science as the piecewise accumulation of true facts, you might well find this disconcerting.  I hope you'll be okay.

Comment: :) No, I'm very familiar with this 'nonlinear' (for the lack of a better term) characteristic of science in general. It's just that linguistics is not (even close to being) my field, so I don't know what's known there and with what degree of certainty. Novices in any field are often surprised both by how easily the experts can answer some questions that would naively seem very hard, as well as by how difficult it can be to answer some questions that would naively seem very easy...

Comment: By the way, in McCawley's own theory of RNR constructions, they are not exceptions to the rule that .only constituents of the same category can be coordinated -- rather one of the coordinated constituents is discontinuous.   Likewise, in Gazdar's theory of RNR, the only thing special about RNR constructions is that the categories  of the coordinated constituents are slash categories.  And in my own theory, 2psg, RNR  constructions arise when "everted" constructions are coordinated.

Comment: That certainly makes sense, that one would prefer a theory where apparent exceptions are not exceptions after all... But do these theories allow the extracted item to be a non-constituent? McCawley's, I gather, doesn't, but that's because he doesn't think that examples like _Smith sells..._ are acceptable. What about yours and Gazdar's?

Comment: No, they are exceptions in all theories, so far as I know.  Is the following okay? "George pushed, and Horace pulled, the gold ingot across the table."  It's suggested by the possibility that some combinations of phrases, while not actually constituents, can masquerade as constituents because they are so easy to interpret (in this case as meaning that the gold ingot moved across the table).

Comment: To me, the _George pushed..._ example sounds fine. However, though I'd like to think I speak English really well, I'm not a native speaker. For what it's worth, it also sounds OK to me when I translate it to my native (Slavic) language...